# Please help me to understand what is particularly wrong with this function

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, flash-cs3

Is there anything wrong with this function?

Im trying to learn actionscript

```
public function navigateToFrame(frameNo:Number)
 {
        var firstNumber:Number = 25;
        var secondNumber:Number = 1;
        trace("crap..."+firstNumber);
        frameNo  =  firstNumber * (frameNo - secondNumber);
        trace("crap..."+frameNo);
        frameNo =  frameNo + secondNumber;
        trace("crap..."+frameNo);
        _root.gotoAndStop(frameNo);
  }
```

I get a compile error that goes like
'Syntax error.

Answer (score 4):

Since you tagged this with `actionsript-3`, I would say that firstly, you are trying to use `_root`, and unless you happen to have a member variable of the same name, then this will not work.

The keyword for the `root` in as3 is `root`, not `_root`

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your answer, this worked

var frameNo:Number


function navigateToFrame(frameNo)
 {
    var firstNumber:Number;
    var secondNumber:Number;
    var frameNoVar:Number;
 
 firstNumber = 25;
 secondNumber = 1;
 frameNoVar = 10;
    trace("crap..." + firstNumber);
    frameNoVar = firstNumber * (frameNo - secondNumber);
    trace("crap..." + frameNoVar);
    frameNoVar = frameNo + secondNumber;
    trace("crap..." + frameNoVar);
    Object(root).gotoAndStop(frameNo);
  }

Comment: @Mnyikka If this answered your question, you should accept the answer (that's the big check icon on the left). Also, please remove all the unreadable code from your comment above - it is not going to help anyone.  If anything else than the `root` call has changed, you can edit and post code snippets to your original question, otherwise just leave the answer as is; it is fairly straight-forward.

Answer (score -1):

In your script, you didn't declare the `frameNo` variable which is required in AS3, instead you're declaring it a function parameter and then trying to set its value within the function, which doesn't make much sense because whatever the value of that parameter is when you call the function, it would not be used. Also, in AS3, the reference for root is stored in an object property called root.

Change your code to this and give it a try:

```
public function navigateToFrame(frameNo:Number)
 {
    var firstNumber:Number = 25;
    var secondNumber:Number = 1;
    var frameNoVar:Number
    trace("crap..." + firstNumber);
    frameNoVar = firstNumber * (frameNo - secondNumber);
    trace("crap..." + frameNoVar);
    frameNoVar = frameNo + secondNumber;
    trace("crap..." + frameNoVar);
    Object(root).gotoAndStop(frameNo);
  }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the way `frameNo` is being used.  It is declared implicitly by being a parameter in the function signature.

Comment: That's what I said too, but I wasn't sure about the purpose of your function. I thought you wanted to do some tracing and still go to and stop at the specified frame. Still, your code shouldn't have gave you a syntax error, just a undefined property access error.